# Append '\n' to a string not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser

This:

```
$('#myDiv').val( $('#myDiv').val() + "\n")
```

is not adding a newline in IE. Is there a say to overcome this problem without actually appending `<br>` instead of \n? I'm doing parsing later in the code and that is why I can't use `<br>` instead of \n.

Comment: What makes you think a newline isn't added? A newline in HTML doesn't generally render as anything visible.

Comment: misunderstood with my (soon to be deleted) answer. Can you give some real html as an example? Why do you need a line break?

Comment: What Wooble said is true. On top of that, you could compact your statement by using the [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method instead.

Comment: @Wooble I add watch with that value, and it is: ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it visible you have to add two new lines.
Use `html` and `<br>` instead.

Blank lines will only be visible if you have another after that or it contains some text.

- [demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/bb97S/): Not visible
- [demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ricardolohmann/bb97S/1/): Visible

Comment: But I'm not interested in <br>

Comment: @Srcee So, I think you have to provide an example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

i just noticed that you are using `val()`. Use `text()` instead of `val()`.

Comment: Not necessarily. That depends on whether #myDiv is an input field or a label/text of some kind.

Comment: then you should give it's a proper id i said this because you used myDiv as id :)